# Bootstrap table with 2 rows and multiple columns with different widths

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a bootstrap table like the example below:

```
-----------------
|       |       |
-----------------
|   |   |   |   |
-----------------
```

How can I easily achieve this? 
I cant find anything about this on the Internet, and i'm a beginner with bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for? I recommend you take a look to the [Grid System](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp):

```css
.row{
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 2px dashed black;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed black;
}

.col-md-6{
  height: 20px;
  border-right : 2px solid black;
  border-left : 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.col-md-3{
  height: 20px;
  border-right : 2px solid black;
  border-left : 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you